# pymongo: How to join two databases (all collections)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I do have the following problem. I get a mongo database with the new weekly data. This weelky update needs to be included in the general mongo database. Basically all collections need to be joined together.

At the moment Im running through all collections of the new weekly file and copy all documents into the overall database. This is a slow process.

Is there any more effective way to do this? Maybe some mongo or pymongo function that I did not see for copying databases or joining collections?

Thank you for any hints.